# Scrollable Dynamic Gridlayout in Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

What I have:
- A dynamic TextWrapper(GridLayout) that includes Images and Labels made from the "description" text out of the SpeciesView.data
- A RecycleView that lets me click through the different texts

The problem is though, that I can't seem to find a way to scroll through the GridLayout (TextWrapper).

I think I am not using the size_hint_y correctly, which should allow the ScrollView to be able to scroll. [The reason found here.](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html?highlight=scrollview#managing-the-content-size-and-position).
The text is always weirdly cut.

So how do I get this ScrollView to work?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

Builder.load_string("""
<ScreenManagement>:
    screen_species: screen_species

    ScreenSpecies:
        id: screen_species
        name: 'screen_species'


<ScreenSpecies>:
    species_text: species_text

    Label:
        pos_hint: {"x": .45, "top": 1}
        size_hint: .1, .1
        text: "Test"

    BoxLayout:
        id: species_layout
        padding: dp(10)
        spacing: dp(10)
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        SpeciesView:
            id: species_list_view

        SpeciesText:
            id: species_text
            name_selected: "" if not species_list_view.name_selected else species_list_view.name_selected


<SpeciesView>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    name_selected: ""

    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        default_size: None, dp(32)
        default_size_hint: .6, None
        size_hint: 1, .9
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: False


<SpeciesText>:
    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: None  


<SelectableLabel>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.05, 0.5, .9, .8) if self.selected else (.5, .5, .5, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<SpeciesLabel>:      
    text_size: self.size       
    size_hint_y: None   


<SpeciesImage>:
    size_hint_y: None
    allow_stretch: True
    keep_ratio: True
    texture_size: dp(20), dp(40)


<TextWrapper>:
    minimum_height: self.height
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: 10
    cols: 1
    size_hint_y: None
""")

class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    pass


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
            rv.name_selected = rv.data[index]['text']
            App.get_running_app().root.screen_species.species_text.update(TextWrapper(rv.data[index]["description"]))
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class ScreenSpecies(Screen):
    pass


class SpeciesView(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SpeciesView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.data = [
            {"text": "Test1", "description": "Test1.textbf\nBla\n |img=image.jpg| Test1.textaf\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla"},
            {"text": "Test2", "description": "Test2.text"},
            {"text": "Test3", "description": "Test3.text"}
        ]


class SpeciesText(ScrollView):
    def update(self, text_wrapper):
        print("Adding TextWrapper {} to SpeciesText ScrollView".format(text_wrapper))
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(text_wrapper)


class SpeciesLabel(Label):
    pass


class SpeciesImage(Image):
    pass


class TextWrapper(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, text="", **kwargs):
        super(TextWrapper, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.content = self.wrap_text(text)

    def wrap_text(self, source):
        text = source.split("|")

        for i in range(0, len(text)):
            if "img=" in text[i]:
                self.add_widget(SpeciesImage(source=text[i][4:]))
            else:
                self.add_widget(SpeciesLabel(text=text[i]))
        return text


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    screen_species = ObjectProperty(None)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


test_app = TestApp()
test_app.run()
```

Thanks as always!

Comment: Can you make a minimal example that reproduce your problem? I cant run this, because `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'text_wrapper'`

Comment: Did that, should work now (?). Thanks for pointing it out! I am not sure how to minimize this further though, sorry :/

Comment: @ZuJiry: I have updated my post with Kivy RstDocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SpeciesText - Using RstDoc

The following example illustrates [Kivy RstDcoument](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.rst.html). It supports long text, [images](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image), and the document is scrollable.

### Snippets

#### kv File

```
<SpeciesText>:
    container: container
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: 1, .9

    RstDocument:
        id: container
```

### Example: SpeciesText - Using RstDoc

#### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string("""
<ScreenManagement>:
    screen_species: screen_species

    ScreenSpecies:
        id: screen_species
        name: 'screen_species'


<ScreenSpecies>:
    species_text: species_text

    Label:
        pos_hint: {"x": .45, "top": 1}
        size_hint: .1, .1
        text: "Test"

    BoxLayout:
        id: species_layout
        padding: dp(10)
        spacing: dp(10)
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        SpeciesView:
            id: species_list_view

        SpeciesText:
            id: species_text
            name_selected: "" if not species_list_view.name_selected else species_list_view.name_selected


<SpeciesView>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    name_selected: ""

    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        default_size: None, dp(32)
        default_size_hint: .6, None
        size_hint: 1, .9
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: False

<SpeciesText>:
    container: container
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: 1, .9

    RstDocument:
        id: container

<SelectableLabel>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.05, 0.5, .9, .8) if self.selected else (.5, .5, .5, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

""")


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    pass


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
            rv.name_selected = rv.data[index]['text']
            App.get_running_app().root.screen_species.species_text.update(rv.data[index]["description"])
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class ScreenSpecies(Screen):
    species_text = ObjectProperty(None)


class SpeciesView(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SpeciesView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.data = [
            {"text": "Test1", "description": "./rstDocs/bearwithus.rst"},
            {"text": "Test2", "description": "./rstDocs/kvDoc.rst"},
            {"text": "Test3", "description": "./rstDocs/sphinxDoc.rst"}
        ]


class SpeciesText(BoxLayout):
    container = ObjectProperty(None)

    def update(self, source):
        print("Adding TextWrapper {} to SpeciesText ScrollView".format(source))
        self.container.source = source


class SpeciesLabel(Label):
    pass


class SpeciesImage(Image):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    screen_species = ObjectProperty(None)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


test_app = TestApp()
test_app.run()
```

### Output: SpeciesText - Using RstDoc

[image: Img03 - RstDoc]
[image: Img04 - RstDoc]
[image: Img05 - RstDoc]

## SpeciesText - Using ScrollView+GridLayout+Label+Image

Use ObjectProperty to hook up to the GridLayout. Please refer to the example for details.

### Snippets

#### kv file

```
<SpeciesText>:
    container: container

    bar_width: 10
    bar_color: 0, 1, 0, 1   # green
    bar_inactive_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
    effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
    scroll_type: ['bars']
    size_hint: (1, None)

    # TextWrapper
    GridLayout:
        id: container
        cols: 1
        spacing: 10
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
```

### Example: SpeciesText - Using ScrollView+GridLayout+Label+Image

#### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

Builder.load_string("""
<ScreenManagement>:
    screen_species: screen_species

    ScreenSpecies:
        id: screen_species
        name: 'screen_species'


<ScreenSpecies>:
    species_text: species_text

    Label:
        pos_hint: {"x": .45, "top": 1}
        size_hint: .1, .1
        text: "Test"

    BoxLayout:
        id: species_layout
        padding: dp(10)
        spacing: dp(10)
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        SpeciesView:
            id: species_list_view

        SpeciesText:
            id: species_text
            name_selected: "" if not species_list_view.name_selected else species_list_view.name_selected


<SpeciesView>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    name_selected: ""

    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        default_size: None, dp(32)
        default_size_hint: .6, None
        size_hint: 1, .9
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: False

<SpeciesText>:
    container: container

    bar_width: 10
    bar_color: 0, 1, 0, 1   # green
    bar_inactive_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
    effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
    scroll_type: ['bars']
    size_hint: (1, None)

    GridLayout:
        id: container
        cols: 1
        spacing: 10
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

<SelectableLabel>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.05, 0.5, .9, .8) if self.selected else (.5, .5, .5, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<SpeciesLabel>:      
    size: self.texture_size       
    size_hint_y: None   


<SpeciesImage>:
    size_hint_y: None
    allow_stretch: True
    keep_ratio: True
    texture_size: dp(20), dp(40)

""")


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    pass


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
            rv.name_selected = rv.data[index]['text']
            App.get_running_app().root.screen_species.species_text.wrap_text(rv.data[index]["description"])
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class ScreenSpecies(Screen):
    species_text = ObjectProperty(None)


class SpeciesView(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SpeciesView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.data = [
            {"text": "Test1", "description": "Test1.textbf\nBla\n |img=kivy_logo.jpg| Test1.textaf\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla\nBla"},
            {"text": "Test2", "description": "Test2.text"},
            {"text": "Test3", "description": "Test3.text"}
        ]


class SpeciesText(ScrollView):
    container = ObjectProperty(None)

    def wrap_text(self, source):
        print("Adding TextWrapper {} to SpeciesText ScrollView".format(source))
        self.container.clear_widgets()
        text = source.split("|")

        for txt in text:
            if "img=" in txt:
                self.container.add_widget(SpeciesImage(source=txt[4:]))
            else:
                self.container.add_widget(SpeciesLabel(text=txt))


class SpeciesLabel(Label):
    pass


class SpeciesImage(Image):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    screen_species = ObjectProperty(None)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


test_app = TestApp()
test_app.run()
```

### Output: SpeciesText - Using ScrollView+GridLayout+Label+Image

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]

Comment: This does make it scrollable, but the whole text is still not displayed on my side? There are missing a lot of Bla's, do you have any idea why it would be cut there?

Comment: In kv file, at `<SpeciesLabel>`, replace `text_size: self.size` with `size: self.texture_size` should fix the problem.

Comment: It does, but only if the Sentence is very short (like in this case "Bla"). If its longer the text disappears. Is the GridLayout maybe too spacious or is it the label?

Comment: How long is the text?

Comment: The actual text is around 2 DINA 4 pages

Comment: There is a text length limitation for Label widget. Recommend that you use [Kivy RstDocument](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.rst.html) because it already has ScrollView, and support long document.

Comment: The problem is that I have images in my text and I think the RstDocument does not support images. But I found a way to format the labels, so its okay :)